# Can a salt value passed to crypt() contain a $ symbol?

Tags: linux, security, md5, crypt, godbolt

Started learning about linux security and reading some articles about MD5 password hashing.

This [godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z1Pqvso57) uses the [crypt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function

```
char *crypt(const char *key, const char *salt);
```

and passes this `salt` value

```
const char *salt = "$1$rockyou";
```

where

- `$1$` is MD5
- `rockyou` is the salt.

**Question**

Suppose the salt contains a `$` symbol, such as `rock$you`, how should it be formatted before passing it to [crypt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `$` in the salt. From the documentation you linked to:

> If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
> followed by a string optionally terminated by "$", then the
> result has the form:
>
> ```
>          $id$salt$encrypted
> ```
>
> ...
> The characters in "salt" and "encrypted" are drawn from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9./]`.

`$` is not in that set because it's used as the delimiter between `salt` and `encrypted`.

Comment: Nice catch about the set `[a-zA-Z0-9./]`. I was expecting there was a method to escape the `$` etc.,...but apparently not. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget that salt is generated by crypt when you hash the first time, not caller-supplied. So it will never put `$` in the salt.